# JavaScript - I want to get a different and random array data until the array ends

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to get an array with unique randomness. I want to add it to the `arr` array with `push` every time and check it with `if`, how can I do it? (or if there is a different solution how can I do it? Like filtering the array)

When I press the button, it creates a biography, I want to get a different bio until the series ends. and random

eg: ["a", "b", "c"]

Random and continuous different data until the sequence ends:

- **clicked:** c
- **clicked:** a
- **clicked:** b

```js
      //bioresponse = api data (.data.bios = array)
      const bios = bioResponse.data.bios.map((bio) => {
        return bio;
      });

      let i = Math.floor(Math.random() * bios.length);
      const pick = (list) => {
        arr.push(list[i]);


        if (i.length == arr) { 

        }
        
        
        return console.log(arr);
      };

      return pick(bios);
```

```html
<button id="bioBtn">get biography</button>
```

It can be with a framework but it's better to have javascript only.

Comment: Can you fix your code up so it runs in the snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I think you require something like this:**

```js
let bios = ["a", "b", "c"];
let arr = [];

function includes(container, value) {
  let returnValue = false;
  let pos = container.indexOf(value);
  if (pos >= 0) {
    returnValue = true;
  }
  return returnValue;
}

document.querySelector("#btn").addEventListener("click", () => {
  // Reset the array if data is finished
  if (bios.length == arr.length) arr = [];

  // Get a random bio
  let bio = bios[Math.floor(Math.random() * bios.length)];

  // Get another until it does not exist in arr
  while (includes(arr, bio)) { //arr.includes(bio) - Internet Explorer NOT SUPPORTED.
    bio = bios[Math.floor(Math.random() * bios.length)];
  }

  // Do something with bio
  console.log("You selected " + bio);

  // Push the bio in arr
  arr.push(bio);

  // I have put this just to see the result
  document.querySelector("#bios").innerHTML = arr;
});
```

```html
<button id='btn'>Button</button>

    <div id='bios'></div>
```

Comment: what if I don't want it to stop after the series is over and I want it to rewind?

Comment: You can just reset the array in that case, just like I edited above.

Comment: `arr.includes` browser support is bad and not supported in internet explorer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Math.random`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) and [`array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to select, return and remove a random item from the array.

[`Math.random`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)

> **MDN Web Docs:**
>
> The `Math.random()` function returns a floating-point, pseudo-random number in the range 0 to less than 1

[`array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

> **MDN Web Docs:**
>
> The `splice()` method changes the contents of an array by removing or replacing existing elements

**Function:**

```js
function getAndRemoveFrom(array) {
  let index = Math.floor((array.length - 1) * Math.random())
  return array.splice(index, 1)
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
let letters = "abcdefg".split("") // ["a", "b", "c", ...]

function getAndRemoveFrom(array) {
  let index = Math.floor((array.length - 1) * Math.random())
  if (!array[index]) return "No items left"
  return array.splice(index, 1)
}

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.querySelector("input").value = getAndRemoveFrom(letters)
})
```

```html
<button>Get letter</button>
<input type="text" disabled="disabled">
```

**Demo (Restarting when items run out):**

```js
let letters = "abcdefg".split("") // ["a", "b", "c", ...]
let clone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(letters))

function getAndRemoveFrom(array) {
  let index = Math.floor((array.length - 1) * Math.random())
  if (!array[index]) return undefined
  return array.splice(index, 1)
}

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", () => {
  let randomLetter = getAndRemoveFrom(clone)
  
  if (!randomLetter) {
    clone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(letters))
    console.log("All letters chosen, returning to start")
    randomLetter = getAndRemoveFrom(clone)
  }
  
  document.querySelector("input").value = randomLetter
})
```

```html
<button>Get letter</button>
<input type="text" disabled="disabled">
```

Comment: what if I don't want it to stop after the series is over and I want it to rewind?

Comment: @Finn take a look at the second snippet in my answer, Is this what you mean by going back to the start when items run out.

Comment: `Array.from` browser support is bad and not supported in internet explorer.

Comment: @Finn I've made an edit and changed the method used, it should now work in internet explorer.